# Correct syntax when using tuple with str.format()

Tags: python, string, format, tuples

I have some troubles affecting tuple values to a `str.format()` method like this:

```
tpl = ("alpha", "omega")
msg = "From {} to {} "
print(msg.format(tpl))
```

Python gives me an `tuple index out of range` error and numbered curly brace can't solve it.

Comment: I found my solution before posting, so I just want to test «answering my own question».

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a script for finding and testing different syntax. 
I'm glad to discover that I can mix it with named argument too.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
""" format syntax with tuple"""

t = ("alpha", "omega")
v = "to"

m = "From {} {} {} "
ms = "From {0} to {1}"
msg = "From {0} {var} {1} "

expr_list = [
    "t, v",
    "m.format(t, v)",
    "m.format(*t, v)",
    "ms.format(t)",
    "msg.format(t, v)",
    "msg.format(t, var=v)",
    "msg.format(*t, var=v)",
]

for num, expr in enumerate(expr_list):
    try:
        print("Expr{}, <{}>: «{}»".format(num, expr, eval(expr)))
    except Exception as except_detail:
        print("Expr{}, <{}> : Exception «{}»".format(num, expr, except_detail))
```

It returns:

```
Expr0, <t, v>: «(('alpha', 'omega'), 'to')»
Expr1, <m.format(t, v)> : Exception «tuple index out of range»
Expr2, <m.format(*t, v)> : Exception «only named arguments may follow *expression (<string>, line 1)»
Expr3, <ms.format(t)> : Exception «tuple index out of range»
Expr4, <msg.format(t, v)> : Exception «'var'»
Expr5, <msg.format(t, var=v)> : Exception «tuple index out of range»
Expr6, <msg.format(*t, var=v)>: «From alpha to omega »
```

Comment: I want to try answering my own question.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `format` with one argument (which is a tuple), while it expects being called with two. It does not automatically unpack tuples and lists.

But you can give format a tuple/list by using it for its `*args` parameter:

```
tpl = ("alpha", "omega")
msg = "From {} to {} "
print(msg.format(*tpl))
```

You can do so for `**kwargs` as well:

```
params = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
print("{a} {b}".format(**params))
```

Comment: Yeah that what I find. I'm new and I want to try answering my own question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the answer to your question, but I can provide you an alternative way of doing.

It looks like you want to define a generic message whose content can vary throughout your process. Then, you can use lambda function. Here is an example :

```
m = lambda X : "from {} {} {}".format(X[0], X[1], X[2])
inputs = ["alpha", "to", "omega"]
scd_inputs = [1, "to", 5]
print m(inputs)
>>> "from alpha to omega"
print m(scd_inputs)
>>> "from 1 to 5"
```

That is, if I understood well, what you want.

In this example I assumed you have constructed a list of inputs, but you can also use `m = lambda s1, s2, s3: "From {} {} {}".format(s1 s2 s3)` that you call like this : `m(first_arg, scd, third)`

I hope it can help

Comment: Hum, I'm not very used to lambda actually. And I do not understand the relation with tuple-usage.